# Cannot build unity scope from qt creator

Tags: application-development, ubuntu-sdk, scopes

I am trying to do the unity scope tutorial from ubuntu developer's site. I follow the following steps

1. Create new project (unity scope)
2. Set name and directory parameters
3. As kit i choose i386 ubuntu sdk.

I didnt' install arm platform because it was suggested by qt creator to use i386 if i am going to use the emulator

I build and get the following error

```
- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 4.8.2
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/i686-linux-gnu-g++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/i686-linux-gnu-g++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:9 (message):
  g++ version must be 4.9!
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/avlahop/development/Ubuntu/build-SoundCloud-UbuntuSDK_for_i386_GCC_ubuntu_sdk_14_04_trusty-Default/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
Command returned 1: schroot -c click-ubuntu-sdk-14.04-i386 -- env DEB_BUILD_ARCH_OS=linux DEB_BUILD_GNU_TYPE=i686-linux-gnu DEB_BUILD_ARCH_BITS=32 DEB_HOST_GNU_TYPE=i686-linux-gnu DEB_HOST_ARCH_CPU=i386 DEB_HOST_GNU_SYSTEM=linux-gnu DEB_HOST_ARCH=i386 DEB_BUILD_ARCH_CPU=i386 DEB_BUILD_GNU_SYSTEM=linux-gnu DEB_BUILD_ARCH_ENDIAN=little DEB_BUILD_MULTIARCH=i386-linux-gnu DEB_HOST_GNU_CPU=i686 DEB_HOST_MULTIARCH=i386-linux-gnu DEB_HOST_ARCH_BITS=32 DEB_HOST_ARCH_OS=linux DEB_HOST_ARCH_ENDIAN=little DEB_BUILD_GNU_CPU=i686 DEB_BUILD_ARCH=i386 cmake /home/avlahop/development/Ubuntu/SoundCloud '-GCodeBlocks - Unix Makefiles'
```

I installed ubuntu-sdk from the ppa as suggested in the ubuntu developer's site. My ubuntu is 14.04LTS

EDIT: The error I get is the following

```
No targets specified and no makefile found. Stop.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this line indicates what the error is:

```
  g++ version must be 4.9!
```

And I guess the reason is because your click chroot (the place where the code is built) is not up-to-date and contains an older version of g++.

To update your chroot:

1. In Qt Creator, go to the **Tools > Options** menu option
2. In the Options dialog, select the **Ubuntu** tab
3. Then click on the **Update** button of your i386 chroot

[image]

That should open up a new dialog that will do the update and show you its progress.

After that, I'd recommend closing the project and reopening it to get cmake to re-run. Alternatively, you can right-click the project name in the project explorer (left-hand side panel) and select the *Run cmake* context menu option.

Comment: Unfortunatelly I still get the same error....Series is trusty.

Comment: @Apostolos ah scopes won't build on trusty. I'd recommend deleting your trusty click target and use the Create Click Target button to create a new one for utopic

Comment: i386 or amd64 for mobile devices? I will use the emulator.

Comment: i386 for emulator (so it runs at native speeds) and armhf for physical devices (e.g. phone)

Comment: It works great ty...One last question...What is the passphrase from the lock screen? Tried "password" but didn't work.

Comment: The password is 0000 - you might want to watch the scopes workshops, where this and more is explained: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL-qBHd6_LXWYSvPX1uyD5ADBMhl41zbcw